# Scraping information from a website using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to scrape information about the aggregated 30-year fixed mortgage rate for the US using VBA in Excel. Here's what I have so far, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong:

```
Sub National_Average()
'
' National_Average Macro
' Record the national average mortgage rate from https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/MORTGAGE30US

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim htmlEle As IHTMLElement
Dim i As Integer

i = 1

Set ie = New InternetExplorer

ie.Visible = True

ie.navigate "https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/MORTGAGE30US"

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

For Each htmlEle In ie.document.getElementsByClassName("series-meta-observation-value")

With Sheets("Demand")

.Range("F2").Value = htmlEle.getElementsByClassName("series-meta-observation-value").textContent

End With

Next

    ie.Quit
End Sub
```

I know it's got something to do with my `For Each` section, specifically the `Range("F2").Value` portion. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are not incrementing `.Range("F2").Value ` if you are expecting more.  So you will need to add a counter and use `.Range("F2").offset(lngCounter,0).value` I think it would just be `htmlEle.textContent`

Comment: I tried that, but I got an error saying "Object variable or with block variable not set". Suggestions?
How do I add a counter? I'm really new at this VBA coding.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: Are you expecting a single value? There may be a better/faster way.

Answer (score 1):

You are looping on each element found by class already, why are you using the .getelementsbyclass() again on the htmlEle to assign the value. it should be like below

```
For Each htmlEle In ie.document.getElementsByClassName("series-meta-observation-value")
With Sheets("Demand")
.Range("F2").Value = .Range("F2").Value & htmlEle.innertext 'accumulating all data on cell
End With
Next htmlEle
```